# AWS server port 25 blocked after few hours of server creation

Tags: amazon-ec2, port, cpanel, whm, blocked

I am running a EC2 large.t3 instance with CentOs.

My server Region is Ohio.

I have installed WHM and it is working fine.

When I created a server PORT 25 working fine. But after few hours port 25 gets blocked. Due to this I'm not ablw to send any email from my webmails.

Here is the snippet..

Just after server setup:

```
[root@ip-172-31-43-92 ~]# telnet 
 aspmx.l.google.com  25
Trying 172.217.214.26...
Connected to aspmx.l.google.com .
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com  ESMTP 
n18si6406443jao.103 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection 
n18si6406443jao.103 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
[root@ip-172-31-43-92 ~]#`
```

After few hours and restart:

```
[root@ip-172-31-43-92 home]# telnet 
aspmx.l.google.com  25
Trying 172.217.212.26...
```

Comment: Note that AWS also seeks to detect abuse. If the email you send may be construed as spam, that might cause AWS to shut down the port.

Comment: SO what's the quick and best solution to fix this issue. Actually I was imported all of my emails from old server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EC2 throttles traffic on port 25 of all EC2 instances by default, but you can request for this throttle to be removed.

This may help you from the AWS website:

[Remove The Port 25 Throttle From Your EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I just submitted a case and waiting for the reply from AWS

Comment: @John-Rotenstein Did you faced this issue, if yes then may I know how much time they took to unblock port.

Comment: I only edited the question. @dr-who can you advise?

Comment: @dr-who Thanks issue resolved now. I followed a article that you shared.